# Combinatorics in a restaurant

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

In a restaurant menu there are 6 types of drinks : Coca cola , lemonade , sprite , wine , tea and diet sprite .

How many people need to order a drink to ensure that at least one drink would be ordered by two people ?

I was thinking about 6 above 2 which is : 6!2! / 4! = 15 . But it doesn't makes sense .

Can someone please verify that ?

Comment: So you want to know, what is the most people who can order a drink, if no drink can be ordered by more than one person? Is that the problem?

Comment: @bof : Yeah , one person can order only one drink .

Comment: You seem to be trying to use a binomial coefficient... "6 above 2" by which you seem to mean $\binom{6}{2}=\frac{6!}{\color{red}{2!}4!} = 15$  (you wrote the $2!$ on the wrong side of the fraction).  These, although useful for counting problems, are not useful here.  What you are looking for is the [pigeon-hole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).  Intuitively, if you have six people and they all are drinking different drinks, if you add another person, will they be drinking the same type of drink as someone else?

Comment: @ JMoravitz : The 7th person would have to have a drink that's similar to someone else's .

Comment: So, if no two people can order the same drink, what's the largest number can be served? Hint: The reason no two people can order the same drink is that you have only one of each kind: one serving of Coca-Cola, one serving of lemonade, etc. What's the most people you can serve?

Comment: @bof : No , why two people cannot order the same drink ? each person can order only one drink , but two people still order the same drink .

Comment: But the ***QUESTION*** is: what's the most people that can be served, ***IF*** no two people order the same drink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct application of the weak form of the [pigeon-hole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) yields the result immediately.

Is it possible for six people to all be drinking different things?

> Yes.  Adam could drink Cocacola, Billy could drink lemonade, Charles could drink sprite, David could drink wine, Emmanuel could drink tea, and Frank could drink diet sprite.

If we add a seventh person, is it still possible for them all to be drinking different things?

> No.  Once we have a seventh person, there must be someone drinking the same thing as someone else.  Why?  Well... suppose that all seven of them were in fact drinking different things.  But then we would have seven different drinks, but there are only six types of drinks available, a contradiction.

Comment: Yes , but we need "at least one drink would be ordered"  , and not exactly one drink .

Comment: @ron and?  Where did I say that exactly one drink?  With seven people, maybe three of them ordered tea and four of them ordered cocacola.  Maybe two ordered cocacola and everyone else ordered something different.  Maybe they all ordered cocacola.  That is what the pigeon-hole principle is used for.  If there are $n$ pigeons and $k$ holes with $n>k$, if we stuff pigeons into holes so that all pigeons are in a hole there must be at least one hole with at least two pigeons in it.

Comment: @ron the question asked for the smallest number such that with that many people we are guaranteed that a drink type is repeated.  The problem of figuring that out is the same problem as finding the most number of people you can have where it is *possible* that they all drink something different.  The numbers will be different by one.  At some point it stops being possible they are all drinking different to being impossible.